# What server hardware are people using for replicated mongodb servers?

Tags: scaling, mongodb, database-replication

Since mongodb, couchdb are for horizontal scaling and have inbuilt support for replication, what hardware is being used for them ?

Specifically looking for hardware for replicable mongodb instances.
Server models etc. would really help.

Adding more info :
3 replications.
OS : Linux.
Size : 11+ tb

Thanks.

Comment: Any idea how much data you want to store? 
How many nodes do you want to replicate to?
Budget constraints?
Operating system you plan to use? (Hint: Use Linux.)

Comment: Christ. 11TB in a mongodb database.. That's going to be Very Memory Hungry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to build a redundant cluster of servers (From my blog): http://tomoconnor.eu/blogish/dedicated-dedicated/

It's really difficult to give specific models and manufacturers, because that kind of information is really specific and localised.  You'll want 2 or more of everything, LOTS of memory, FAST disks.
Anything by Dell or HP that fits that category will be fine.

Bare in mind that Mongo uses lots of in-memory space for data, so you'll want a server that can take craploads of DIMMs.  Perhaps an HP Bladesystem might be a better fit than 1U rack servers.

==edit==

3-way replication, and 11TB+ of database.
That is an enormous amount of data.  Bear in mind that Mongo stores/caches a lot of data in RAM.  Assuming you'll want some kind of speed, you should definitely be looking at some very big servers.  Earlier on we were discussing this in [The Comms Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) and came to the conclusion that if you wanted to store as much of it in memory, then you'd have to shard it very heavily, and have multiple shard servers, to get your redundancy goals.

This is not going to be a cheap project.

Comment: Checking your blog as I type. Oftopic - I've heard Cisco 55xx series switches pose problems with failover and both try to take control causing nasty issues. e.g. heartbeat getting lost when high traffic hits.

Comment: I've never seen those problems, and we had 55xx serving some seriously high bandwidth sites at $lastjob.

Answer (score 0):

Odd question, you've not really told us anything to help us? You don't mention whether you're using Windows, Linux or OSX? nor your scaling requirements, database design, user volumes, network setup, physical environment, budget, timescales - nothing at all!

Nobody will be able to answer this as it stands other than "they run it on supported hardware", which could be pretty much anything bought in the last few years.

Comment: Sorry, have added more info. to the question.